# Changing video quality in PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, videoquality

I am trying to make a video player. I'm asking about convert the video from 720p quality (HD) to 240p (SD), how can I do it? Can I use PHP or JavaScript to do it?

Comment: "please send me the method thanks" - wow :) That's not how the SO works.

Comment: Look into something like ffmpeg

Comment: if any one want to resolve this problem you can use ffmpeg tools install this tool in the site it's so simply but it's take time to install www.ffmpeginstaller.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the most powerful tool for your purpose is [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)

Comment: but it's not working with php 5.3

Comment: are you sure, http://philbayfield.com/2009/10/25/compile-ffmpeg-php-for-php-5-3-yes-it-does-work/

Comment: but how can i install it first in windows Xampp ?

Comment: why do you need server on windows?

Comment: because i'm web developer i prefer to develop my web sites on windows just i think it's better than linux for me to develop on windows so for that i need it on windows

Comment: as i see ffmpeg is available on windows. you can find how to install it on documentation

Comment: @MulhamAryan linux is the best